# Get the height of a tag in Firefox, which I set as display: table; in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

This question is not a duplicate. I have the following code:

```
<header id="header">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="table-row">
      <nav id="menubar">Welcome</nav>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
      <nav id="models">something blah blah blah</nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

And in the `style.css` file I have:

```
.table {
  display: table;
  width:100%;
}
.table-row {
  display: table-row;
}
```

The reason for `display: table-row;` is to use `vertical-align: middle;`. Now the problem is that I can't get the height of the `header` in Firefox. I tried:

```
var header = document.getElementsByTagName("header");
var height = header[0].offsetHeight;
```

And

```
alert($("#header").height());
```

And

```
alert(header[0].offsetHeight || header[0].clientHeight);
```

And

```
var height = header[0].clientHeight;
```

But none of them worked in FF, although I get correct results in Chrome. Is there a solution?

Comment: Could you setup a fiddle please

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the height of header when added `height: 200px` in #header.
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DSjLJ/)

**Edit**

Okay! I got it.

add `table-layout: fixed;` to your table class and then define the height as your wish of table-row class

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DSjLJ/1/)

Comment: thanks for your demo, but you see the two nav inside the header ? well i want these to determine the height of the header, i have another nav below them and i want to set the margin-top according to the height of the two nav inside the header, so i made a script that will get the height, so i don't need to calculate the margin-top manually...

Comment: i'll try to get the height of the two nav and then set it to the height of the header and use your way ..

Comment: thanks but it didn't work either, tried everything, i'll go for setting it manually, i have another problem in FF, first time the page loaded, the style will be corrupted, but when i refresh it again, it will be fixed....

Comment: this is behaving your browser cache so later it will be fixed.